# Why do plugins often ask to add <?php do_action('plugin_name_hook'); ?> in to templates?

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions

I have seen many plugin installations require to add

```
<?php do_action('plugin_name_hook'); ?>
```

inside the templates files. What does it do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please explain me what the do\_action does](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167260/please-explain-me-what-the-do-action-does)

Comment: @mayersdesign I know, what do_action does, just don't understand what is the tag 'plugin_name_hook' does. Couldn't find add_action to that inside the plugin

Comment: Look for do_action :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, sorry I understand. I can only assume that the plugins are shipping with "default help text", because plugin_name_hook is just placeholder text for whatever the plugins - specific - do_action is called.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the alternative, calling an API by `api_call()` is worse, as when the plugin is deactivated you will get a php error.

you could have done something like

```
if (function_exists('api_call'))
  echo api_call();
```

but it is more verbose and less elegant, and the hook way allows the plugin author to change the name of the function actually handling the hook.

in addition when you use an action, other code can remove the action, which might be a good or a bad thing depending on context.

My personal opinion is that if your theme needs to call a function, just call it (with the `if exists` protection). this will make your code more readable. You can add a comment at that code block that this function is an API by plugin YYY.

And on the flip side, if you write a plugin, just commit to function names and properly expose an API. hooks are supposed to be an exception/variation on the control flow, and not replace it.